# How can I put the elements of a list into an indexed column

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:  {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 11}.  I want an indexed column with 1 element on each line with 1 space between the index and the element:

```
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 1 
5 1
6 3
7 4
8 11
```

I need such a column so as to create a b-file to upload to Sloane's OEIS.  Maybe someone knows a more automated way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 11};
StringRiffle[MapIndexed[{#2 - 1, #1} &, list], " ", " ", ""]
```

Or

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 11}; 
StringRiffle[Transpose[{Range[Length@list] - 1, list}], " ", " "]
```

**UPDATE**

Re-reading the original question, I think there might have been a formatting problem.

> I want an indexed column with 1 element on **each line** with 1 space between the index and the element

One might interpret that to mean that the expected output included newlines like this:

```
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 1
5 1
6 3
7 4
8 11
```

If that is desired, then alter the separator specifications to get these variants:

```
StringRiffle[MapIndexed[{#2 - 1, #1} &, list], "\n", " ", ""]
```

and

```
StringRiffle[Transpose[{Range[Length@list] - 1, list}], "\n", " "]
```

Comment: Yes,  Thank You!  It is the format in your update that I needed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

```
alist = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 11};

StringRiffle[
 ToString /@ MapIndexed[Sequence @@ {First@#2 - 1, #1} &, alist]]
```

> "0 0 1 0 2 1 3 0 4 1 5 1 6 3 7 4 8 11"

OR

```
MapIndexed[Sequence @@ {First@#2 - 1, #1} &, alist] // 
 Multicolumn[#, {1, Automatic}] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've broken it out into steps so that what I am doing is more clear.
Initial List:

```
list1 = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 11};
```

Index List:

```
list2 = Range[0, Length[list1] - 1];
```

Interleave (Riffle) the two lists and convert to strings:

```
list3 = ToString /@ Riffle[list2, list1]
```

`{"0", "0", "1", "0", "2", "1", "3", "0", "4", "1", "5", "1", "6",  "3", "7", "4", "8", "11"}`

Add spaces:

```
List4 = Riffle[list3, " "]
```

`{"0", " ", "0", " ", "1", " ", "0", " ", "2", " ", "1", " ", "3", " ", "0", " ", "4", " ", "1", " ", "5", " ", "1", " ", "6", " ", "3", " ", "7", " ", "4", " ", "8", " ", "11"}`

Join the elements in the list to one string:

```
string = StringJoin[List4]
```

`"0 0 1 0 2 1 3 0 4 1 5 1 6 3 7 4 8 11"`

Collapsed into a single line it would be:

```
StringJoin@
 Riffle[ToString /@ Riffle[Range[0, Length[list1] - 1], list1], " "]
```